# Will Googlebot correctly handle <link rel="canonical" ref="{{url}}>" for angularjs page

Tags: angularjs, web-crawler, canonical-link

Is it safe to use`<link rel="canonical" ref="{{canonical_url}}" />` in an angularjs page, or is there a preferred way to handle this?

Google is now automatically crawling and rendering javascript, which is great for angularjs sites. But, I'm concerned that Googlebot may not wait for the rendering when deciding about canonical pages, and I don't want to mess up our site by having Googlebot think all pages are "url".

Using Google's Webmaster Tools, I can see that Google's crawler can render the pages just fine, but I'm not sure how to tell how it's dealing with a canonical tag. Other reading implies that Googlebot stops reading/rendering a page if it sees a canonical tag for another page it has already processed.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure about Googlebot executing the JavaScript code. In my experience, the webmaster tools shows the rendered page, with the JS executed, but in reality, Googlebot doesn't actually execute the JavaScript, and indexes all the angular expressions. Shame on Google.

Comment: @JB Nizet: I can see things indexed in Google snippets that would not be possible if it weren't executing javascript, so at least some of this is working in my case.

Answer (score 2):

As  @JB Nizet mentioned, as I witnessed, Google as of Sep 25 2015 executes JS, render it properly in webmaster but more like "for demo". En mass production links still not executed RELIABLY by Google ( sometime not at all, sometime quite good).

So we still have to use prerender.io (which is quite good). But attention: use the one with phantomjs2, phantomjs1 is not good at parsing/reading angular apps.

IMPORTANT things: they do support httpCode, and all your double curly braces.

Good luck!

Source: my painful days setting up SEO for our angular platform

Answer (score 0):

Google will render and index plain SPA without any static html snapshots.

**BUT:** i have a project with change over to https. usually i dont redirect with 301 but just add https in the canonical tag. on this site google has not yet recognized the change.

Same time on another project, same changeover to https with same code but with html snapshots included:
google has recognized the change to https and right version is in in the search results.

i wrote my own directive to have a nice seo header with canonical tags. its better to use your pages head tag as directive call. 
https://github.com/w11k/w11k-angular-seo-header

If you want to prerender your site do not use a moron service like prerender but simply add a task to your build process. Setup with Grunt/Gulp is about 15 mins.. once!

Comment: What if my website has hundreds of thousands of pages, which are generated on the fly. (User profile pages, posts they add etc.) How do we still avoid 'moronic' services like prerender, or setting up our own phantomjs servers.